# selected nested polymer element innerHTML missing style

Tags: javascript, polymer

currently i am trying to access nested element. as I understand chrome supports shadow dom so i can access the inner html of a nested element like this

```
this.$.grade.$printable.root.innerHTML
```

in firefox which uses shady dom

```
this.$.grade.$printable.innerHTML
```

the problem is in the case of firefox the innerHTML is missing the local dom css while in chrome it is rendering correctly

is there anyway to preserve the local dom css when querying the element

**example**

in chrome

```
console.log(this.$.grade.root.innerHTML)
```

returns

```
<style scope="grades-view">grades-printable {
  display: none;
}

@media only print {
grades-card, grades-table {
  display: none;
}

grades-printable {
  display: block;
}

}</style>


  <iron-ajax auto="" handle-as="json" hidden=""></iron-ajax>

  <grades-card></grades-card>
```

in firefox

```
console.log(this.$.grade.innerHTML)
```

returns

```
<iron-ajax class="style-scope grades-view" auto="" handle-as="json" hidden=""></iron-ajax>

<grades-card class="style-scope grades-view"></grades-card>
```

Comment: Could you show some examples of what you're getting back, and what this "local dom style" looks like ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be quite careful with what you are doing because of the issue of distributed nodes (when a `<content>` element appears inside a `<template>` of a custom element, that content is filled in with stuff form (from a dom perspective) nodes elsewhere in the dom tree.  You should use the `Polymer.dom()` functions to manipulate things consistently.  See the developers guide for a fuller explanation and the functions that are provided.